# Text field from a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and when the user clicks the item, I want to get the text that they clicked on (not the ID). At the moment, I have this:

```
ListView vehList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
vehList.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

...and in the onClickListener:

```
String vehNameStr = vehList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

...but this just gets me a long string of text unrelated to what my ListView is displaying.

EDIT: listView populated by cursor:

```
Cursor mpgCur = mpgDB.query(dbMain.TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION, null, null, null, null, null);

// build a listView
String[] fromColumns = {dbMain.VEHICLE_NAME};
int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};

vehAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_2, mpgCur, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
setListAdapter(vehAdapter);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The clickListener gives you the index of the item clicked. From that you can get the Object directly from your array/list that you supplied to the ListView (`array[index]` or `list.get(index)`) and do whatever you need to with it. Are you using a custom ArrayAdapter? Can we see the code where you instantiate and populate the ListView and the whole OnClickListener.onClick() method please?

Comment: ListView populated by cursor - adding code now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter passed in to `onItemClick` is the view within the `ListView` that was clicked. You could call `findViewById` on it, cast the result to a `TextView`, and call `getText()`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(...);
    String text = textView.getText();
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, onItemClick also gives you the clicked position. You could simply call `getItem(position)` on your adapter if you keep the adapter as a member of your activity/fragment.

Comment: I can see that might work (will test in a minute) but what is the point of 'getItemAtPosition'? What does that get you any more than 'position' already provides?

Comment: That depends. What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: Thanks, that does work although seems to be a little bit of a long way round to get such a simple bit of data.

Comment: Thats' why I mentioned `getItem(position)`. Adapters bind data to views on screen. You could access that element of the backing data directly, which may or may not be easier and more useful to you than inspecting the view it was bound to.